# Is it true that in React, when the Context changes, every component under the Provider re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

There is a trend that engineering teams move from Redux to Context.  However, is it true that when the context change, then all components under the context provider will re-render?

Or is it only the components using the `useContext` hook will re-render? If some components are under a different context provider, then they will not get re-rendered?

It may appear that it will be more components re-rendering than using Redux, but my experience is that the performance is not an issue (in most cases I have seen), so I don't know if it is due to this that engineer teams move from Redux to Context to make the coding simpler.

Comment: "Is it true that in React, when the Context changes, every component under the Provider re-renders?" - Yes, it's true. "There is a trend that engineering teams move from Redux to Context." - Is there? And why? Redux and the React Context API solve two different engineering concerns.

Answer (score 2):

> is it true that when the context change, then all components under the context provider will re-render?

Yes, by default. And that's not specific to context: If *any* component rerenders, then all it's children will rerender too, unless you take steps to prevent it. The only thing unique about a context provider here is that they're usually pretty close to the top of the component tree, so they can cause a lot of children to rerender.

If this is an issue, you'll typically address it by using `React.memo` on a component that's a child of the context provider. This will skip rendering, and thus the entire subtree of components will also be skipped, except for components which have explicitly opted into that context via `useContext`